# transfer an array value to text field in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

Here i want to transfer the array value to the input type through an need to pass that value to the ajax, in order to get that i had done my code like this please have a look

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    var values = $("input[name='return_quantity[]']")
          .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
    alert(values);
    var for_transfer=$('#for_transfer').val(values);
    alert(for_transfer);
});
```

and i want to transfer this `for_transfer` to the input field,my input type looks like this

`<input type="hidden" name="for_transfer[]" id="for_transfer" class="form-control">`

here `for_transfer` value goes empty and my `values` value getting is `0,1,2`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
var values = $("input[name='return_quantity[]']")
      .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
alert(values);
var for_transfer=$('#for_transfer').val(values);
alert($('#for_transfer').val());
});
```